# First Load Kendo UI Grid

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

I have a problem with Kendo UI Grid. When I load the data (from an async request that return a json data format), the grid does not render rightly the footer of the grid. When I click to order or page the grid, it render fine. My question is: How to correct this bug?

Look the images.

First load:

[image]

After the sort by code, the footer looks ok.

[image]

If someone knows how can I correct this bug and share it, I really appreciate.

Thank you.

### Client side code (Kendo Version: v2012.3.1114)

```
<script>

    var grid;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var serviceUrl = "@Url.Action("GetAsyncData", "Home")";

        grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                type: "json",
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        dataType: "json",
                        url: serviceUrl,
                        cache: false
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    data: "data",
                    total: "count",
                    model: {
                        id: "Id"
                    }
                }               
            },
            height: 400,
            toolbar: [{ text: "New", className: "add-button" }],
            groupable: true,
            sortable: true,
            pageable: false,
            selectable: true,
            resizable: true,
            columns: [
                {
                    field: "Code",
                    title: "Cód.",
                    width: "150px",
                    filterable: true,
                    groupable: false,
                    sortable: true,
                    resizable: true
                },
                {
                    field: "Name",
                    title: "Nome",
                    filterable: true,
                    groupable: false,
                    sortable: true,
                    resizable: true
                }, {
                    field: "Contact",
                    title: "Contato",
                    encoded: false,
                    filterable: true,
                    groupable: true,
                    sortable: true,
                    resizable: true
                },
                { command: { name: "Editar", text: "", className: "edit-button custom-button edit" }, title: "", width: "50px", filterable: false, sortable: false, groupable: false, resizable: false },
                { command: { name: "Detalhes", text: "", className: "detail-button custom-button detail" }, title: "", width: "50px", filterable: false, sortable: false, groupable: false, resizable: false },
                { command: { name: "Excluir", text: "", className: "delete-button custom-button delete" }, title: "", width: "50px", filterable: false, sortable: false, groupable: false, resizable: false }
            ]
        }).data("kendoGrid");

        $("#grid").delegate(".add-button", "click", function (e) {
            window.location = '@Url.Action("Create")';
        });
    });

</script>

<div id="grid"></div>
```

Comment: Can you share some code that reproduces it? Can you post some code in jsfiddle.net?

Comment: How does the grid look if you don't pass it a datasource?

Comment: take a look at my edits.

Answer (score -3):

What version of Kendo are you using? I am not able to replicate the behavior using Q3 version